# Use of request.getSession(false) in TagLib of Grails throws exception

Tags: grails

I am trying to use the below code in TagLib of Grails 2.3.5.

```
class LoginTagLib {
   def loginControl = {
  if(request.getSession(false) && session.user){
    out << "Hello ${session.user.login} "
    out << """[${link(action:"logout",controller:"user"){"Logout"}}]"""
} 
else {
    out << """[${link(action:"login",
    controller:"user"){"Login"}}]"""
}
}
```

}

I am getting following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.session() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [false]
Possible solutions: getSession(boolean), getSession()
    racetrack.LoginTagLib$_closure1.doCall(LoginTagLib.groovy:9)
    D__JAVA_GRAILS_WORKSPACE_RaceTrack_grails_app_views_layouts__header_gsp.run(_header.gsp:7)
    D__JAVA_GRAILS_WORKSPACE_RaceTrack_grails_app_views_layouts_main_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(main.gsp:22)
    D__JAVA_GRAILS_WORKSPACE_RaceTrack_grails_app_views_layouts_main_gsp.run(main.gsp:25)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: There's no point trying to use `getSession(false)` as so many other things in Grails always create the session by default without checking whether or not it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
def user = session?.user

if (user) {
    out << "Hello ${session.user.login} "
    out << """[${link(action:"logout",controller:"user"){"Logout"}}]"""
}
```

Comment: The point of `getSession(false)` is that it won't start a session if there isn't one already available (if something else has called `getSession()` earlier in the request process, or if the request included a session cookie).  Simply calling `session?` is different as that will always create a session.  But in practice so many other places in Grails assume a session that it's not worth bothering about trying to avoid session creation, something else will almost certainly have created one already.

Comment: Thanks Ian for quick answer. I used
    request.session
to check for the session and accordingly proceed.

Comment: @IanRoberts can you give some examples of these "other things" that create session? I know lots of plugins use the session (e.g. spring security), but I don't think of anything in Grails core that uses the session

Comment: @Don I have very rarely seen any case when debugging my grails applications where it _didn't_ set a session cookie but that may be the plugins I'm using.  Certainly anything that attempts to read or write the `flash` will trigger a session (e.g. `<g:if test="${flash.message}">` in the default scaffolding).

Comment: @IanRoberts oh yeah, flash, I forgot about that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think,   **reuqest.getSession(false)** have to work.
Due to [grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Tag%20Libraries/request.html):

> the request object is an instance of the Servlet API's HttpServletRequest class

Where is **public HttpSession getSession(boolean create);** in **HttpServletRequest**

By the log, we can see, **org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade** also has **getSession(boolean)**

In my opinion, you have some troubles with plugins or libs.